# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-?"

Tags: maxent

I'm getting an error in Maxent which arises from one of the output files created by Maxent, in this case the _ASCII_novel.asc at row 159 column 444. However, the data in this position appears to be OK.

I saw a similar question where the error noted is For input string: "Z^,,," which seemed to be caused by an invalid file type (GeoTiff not .asc), but Maxent didn't seem to have a problem using my .asc files before the output file produced an error, so I don't think this must be the problem.

I have run Maxent without my bias file, and this avoids the error.

If it's of any help the rest of the error reads:

```
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
at density.MyScanner.nextFloat(MyScanner.java:46)
at density.LazyGrid.readRowAsc(LazyGrid.java:166)
at density.LazyGrid.readRow(LazyGrid.java:74)
at density.LazyGrid.eval(LazyGrid.java:87)
at density.LazyGrid.hasData(LazyGrid.java:81)
at density.Grid.minmax(Grid.java:156)
at density.tools.Novel.makeNovel(Novel.java:134)
at density.tools.Novel.go(Novel.java:99)
at density.Runner.makeNovel(Runner.java:618)
at density.Runner.start(Runner.java:563)
at density.GUI$7.construct(GUI.java:342)
at density.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:131)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

So a few things about this question:

1. On second inspection there was indeed a problem with the file - there was -? at the specified location.
2. The issue was not with my bias file but with one of my environmental layers.
3. The Answer: Basically, one of my habitat layers only had several cells with that habitat, thus none of my species records had data for this layer, and was throwing up the -?. After removing the layer, it worked fine.